# Should you use mouthwash after sugary food

Tags: dentistry, brushing-teeth, mouthwash

Brushing your teeth after eating sugary foods can damage your teeth and you should wait at least an hour after. For example, take this quote from a [paper on "Sugar-Sweetened Beverages"](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5030497/):

> Brushing, immediately after consumption of SSB [Sugar-Sweetened Beverages] drinks should be
> avoided because the enamel becomes transition-ally softened. Patients
> should wait an hour before brushing to allow teeth to remineralize and
> enamel to harden.

However, does using a non-alcoholic fluoride mouthwash immediately after eating sugary/sweet foods also damage your teeth? I have found no references which address this subject.

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and the reasons mentioned in [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: Probably best to cut the link to a commercial product and just go generic - this'll avoid closure as spam. Also, get rid of the "personal advice" aspect, another reason for closure.

Answer (score 1):

There are studies, e.g.  [The effect of chlorhexidine on dental calculus formation: an in vitro study](https://bmcoralhealth.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12903-018-0517-3), that have shown that using these mouthwashes increased the calculus formation (petrification of dental plaque biofilm).

I've received advice from dental hygienists to stop using mouthwashes for this very reason.

You would probably be better of rinsing your mouth with plain water.  And brushing your teeth (after an hour) and flossing before using a mouthwash.

> It is necessary to disrupt the biofilm prior to the start of a CHG mouthwash in order to reduce the side effects associated with this procedure